# PreviewMouseRightButtonUp does not fire when Context Menu is open

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, mouseevent

If I right-click on an Image I get the following events (shown in order):

1) MouseRightButtonDown

2) PreviewMouseRightButtonUp

3) MouseRightButtonUp

At this point my Application displays a context menu.  If that is open, and I right click on the image again I only get this event:

1) MouseRightButtonDown

Nor sure what to do to get these events when a context menu is open?

Answer (score 0):

How do you track events? What code do you have? Have you checked events with [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/)? It has really nice feature where you can track all routed events. It always helps you to find out who handles what:
[image: alt Snoop sample]
<sub>(source: [blois.us](http://blois.us/Snoop/pics/EventsViewD.PNG))</sub>

And it shows that PreviewMouseUp is always coming, no matter ContextMenu is open or not...

PS: I know, I shouldn't write this before you answer previous questions, but have you tried:

```
img.AddHandler(PreviewMouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(ImgPreviewMouseUp), true /* Handled events too */);
void ImgPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
 // 
}
```

:)